# Cant Right Click ANYWHERE all of a sudden?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, context-menu, right-click, mouse-click

Suddenly I cannot right click anywhere on my Manjaro Linux system. I think VirtualBox might have something to do with this, but I am not even 50% on that.

I can't right click my Desktop, within Chromium, Thunar, icons, folders, anywhere!

And it often takes 2 clicks on a window to activate it. I am so lost, please please help!

Also **I seem to not be able to use the keyboard (or just the PrintScreen key) when these blue underlines are beneath a word on several window menu-items in which activate after clicking.**

Here is what things look like that didn't look like before this problem started:

[image: example screenshot 1]

[image: example screenshot 2]

[image: example screenshot 3]

Notice the weird underlines or underscores...

So much love to whoever can shed some light...

***Update:***
Also cant ***Left Click*** Chromium 3 dot menu button now too...

Comment: Alt or control or shift keys held down? Give each one a few taps and see if that helps.

Comment: Nope, I unplugged my keyboard and still the problem is there. I just restored my system hard drive and the problem still exist. Meaning the setting is somewhere held within the hard drive of my home folder. Some settings somewhere. Darn nobody knows??? Darnnetttt!

Answer (score 1):

OMG I FIXED IT!

I went to Settings Editor > xfwm4

Clicked on Reset on one of the properties in there, it disappeared so I don't know exactly which one, but immediately fixed!

Yay! :)

screenshot of Settings Editor where the problem was fixed

[image: screenshot of Settings Editor where the problem was fixed]

Comment: Also, if that doesn't work, running this command should do it:        
`rm /home/.config/xfce4/xfconf/xfce-perchannel-xml/xfce4-settings-editor.xml` Hope this helps someone who encounters the same issue.